# Analyze iOS version distribution of a specific app in AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, deployment-target

Is it possible to analyze the distribution of iOS 13 of one of my app using AppStore Connect?

**Background:**

I have an app in the AppStore which currently uses iOS 11.0 as deployment target. Now I would like to use an Apple API which requires a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0.

I don't want to exclude many user, If I would set the deployment target in the next version to iOS 13.0.

I have no 3rd party analytic tools integrated in my app.

**Additional question:**

If I would change deployment target to iOS 13, can users with lower iOS still download the last compatible version of my app which uses lower deployment target?

Comment: If you have no analytics tool then you don't have any information on iOS versions of your users - you can use general stats on iOS 13 adoption.  The answer to your second question is people can still download the last compatible version if they have already purchased your app.  New users below iOS 13 would not be able to download it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can *partially* do this.

Go over to App Store Connect > App Analytics and then check both **impressions** and **app units**. In the dropdown filter menu at the top choose platform version.

[image]

Here you can see downloads/sales plotted by the different OS versions. Same  goes for impressions or product page views. Based on those numbers you should be able to make your decision.

Once you set a specific deployment target, previous customers can still download the last compatible version. In App Store Connect, you can manage this under "My apps" > Click on the app > "Pricing and Distribution" > Scroll down to "Last-Compatible Version Settings"

Comment: Not the most comfortable and transparent way from Apple how to analyze the data, but it will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In 2023, you can generate a nice report on the iOS versions as follows:

1. Go to App Store Connect > App Analytics.
2. Click Metrics on top of the page.
3. In the first dropdown, choose Usage > Active Last 30 Days.
4. In the second dropdown, choose Platform Version.